# Generate paths in using Networkx graph

Tags: graph, path, networkx

I am trying to generate some random paths for a pair of nodes. My networkx graph has 44012 nodes and 84154 edges. Following is my code to generate the paths:

```
   for n1 in G.nodes_iter():
#        print (G.node[n1]['id'])
        i+=1
        if (i > 10):
            break;
        for n2 in G.nodes_iter():
#            print (G.node[n2]['id'])
            if(G.node[n1]['id']==G.node[n2]['id']):
                continue
            i += 1
            if(i>10):
                break;
            if(nx.has_path(G,n1,n2)):
                shortest_path_length = nx.shortest_path_length(G,n1,n2)
                paths= (nx.all_simple_paths(G,n1,n2,cutoff=shortest_path_length+1))
                print(paths)
                for path in paths:
                    print("hello")
```

I get the following output:

```
<generator object _all_simple_paths_graph at 0x03690F60>
hello
```

I think the execution is stuck in the last for loop. I am not sure what is wrong actually.

Any suggestions to generate 20 simple paths for a pair of nodes?

Thanks!

Comment: Q1: How do you know there are 20 simple paths?  It looks to me that there is a single path between those nodes.

Comment: Q2: why not just test if `n1==n2` rather than `G.node[n1]['id']==G.node[n2]['id']` ? The only reason for your test would be if multiple nodes have the same `'id'`

Comment: Q3: Have you noticed that `i` is incrementing in the main for loop and the nested for loop.  Is that intentional?  You should also read up on `enumerate` rather than doing it the way you have.

Comment: Thanks for your response.

Comment: Q1: I am not sure if there are exactly 20 simple paths or not. I just want to create 20 simple paths for 10 different (source, destination) pairs.

Comment: Q2: Thanks! I would better use n1==n2.

Comment: Q3: Thanks again! I just do it intentionally to check the some of the initial paths.